# Como controlar o tamanho da imagem em um carousel do bootstrap?

Tags: html5, css3, carousel

**HTML**

```
<!--Carousel-->
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active imagem">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="static/img/aviao.png" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="static/img/aviao.png" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="static/img/aviao.png" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
<!--Fim do Carousel-->
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.imagem {
    height: 400px !impotant;
}
```

Comment: Como assim controlar o tamanho?  O que mais precisamente vc quer fazer e como quer que a imagem responda?

Comment: Não se preocupe, já consegui resolver, muito obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Legal, já que resolveu considere postar a resposta ou apagar a pergunta, já que ela foi resolvida sem precisar de resposta ;)

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<!--Carousel-->
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="static/img/aviao.png" height="400px" !important alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="static/img/aviao.png" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="static/img/aviao.png" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
<!--Fim do Carousel-->
```

Acabou que colocar `height="400px" !important` me fez poder controlar o tamanho da imagem dentro da `div`.